# mongoose versioning - __v is 1 after saving

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm writing an app using node, express and mongoose. When I use `object.save` to save (upsert) my object in mongodb, `object.save` returns the object after receiving the updates in mongo. This returned object has `__v: 1`. When I check the object in mongodb, its `__v` remains `0`, which is what is expected.

To have my object with correct `__v`, I do a `model.findById` just after saving, which returns the object with correct `__v`, which is `0`. Then I return this object to client (html page).

Has somebody experienced this issue? Why is this happening? Am I missing something here?

I'm using (unstable) mongoose version 4 (not in production, just development).

Comment: Is this `object` a member of an array and does your `upsert` statement use one of these operations: `$pull`, `$pullAll`, `$pop`, `$set` of an entire array, `$push`, `$pushAll` or `$addToSet`?

Comment: Well, the object has an array, which I don't change at all. I just make a small change in the object but the array is untouched. When I save the object (riesgo.save(function (err, savedItem, numberAffected) {) the object returns (when "save" succeds) with its  __v as 1. Off course __v remains as 0 in mongodb, which is fine, because (as per documentation) __v only changes when you change the position of elements in an array, which I'm not doing.